How to read the file from a Shape added with Shapes.AddPicture?
I have a macro that adds images to a sheet with
Private Function attachImageMac(ByVal FName As String, ByVal imageName As String)
    Dim img
    Dim imgWidth, imgHeight As Long
    
    imgWidth = -1
    imgHeight = -1
    
    Set img = Sheets("Receipt images").Shapes.AddPicture(fileName:=FName, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
        savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=10, top:=10, width:=imgWidth, height:=imgHeight)
    img.Name = imageName
    img.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    Set img = Nothing 
End Function

So, it should save the image file with the shape, but how can I access the file afterwards? The Shape documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape was not providing any obvious ways to access it.

What do you mean with "access" the file, what do you want to do with it? As far as I know, it's not possible to for example to read it and write it back as image file.

It can be done, but it requires a lot of API work.

What you really mean by "how can I access the file"? Do you want accessing the file located in the used FName variable?

It's not clear what you want to achieve, but you can "access" the image using img.Copy. and paste it into a graphics program.

Yeah, I want to read the image file and send it to our API. And by image file I mean also pdf files with multiple pages. Shapes.AddPicture is able to add the first page of the pdf file as a picture, but later, I would need to send all the pages to our API. But looks like it is not possible with the shapes.
On Windows, we use CustomXMLNodes to save the whole file, but Mac does not support those. So, looking for a better solution for Mac.

If what you mean by "how can I access the file" extracting the inserted picture file full name, you should add a single code line, using a shape string property to memorize the respective full name. Otherwise, Excel does not know any information related to the used inserted picture file:
Private Sub attachImageMac(ByVal FName As String, ByVal imageName As String)
    Dim img As Shape
    
    Set img = Sheets("Receipt images").Shapes.AddPicture(fileName:=FName, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
        savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=10, top:=10, width:=-1, height:=-1)
    img.Name = imageName
    img.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    img.Title = FName 'this line is necessary to memorize the file full name
    Set img = Nothing 
End Sub

Then, call the next Function, using the same imageName as used in the above code:
Function extractPictureOriginalFile(imgName As String) As String
   Dim img As Shape
   Set img = ActiveSheet.Shapes(imgName)
   extractPictureOriginalFile = img.Title
End Function

It should be called using the next testing Sub:
Sub testExtractPictureFile()
  Dim imgName As String
  imgName = "My Picture" 'use here your previously used/allocated name!
  Debug.Print extractPictureOriginalFile(imgName) 'it will return the file full name
                                                  'Use Ctrl + G to open Immediate Window
End Sub

It will return the full name of the previously inserted picture.
If you have a list of the inserted files full name and imgName has been extracted from the respective full name, as the file name without path, you can extract the respective information by correlation between the shape name and its used full file name from that list...

@Mika Didn't you find some time to try the above suggested solution? Did you understand what the above code does?  Do you want sending to your "API" from the same computer where you inserted the picture/file? Or you want doing it from a different computer, too? I would say that it is at least polite to send some feedback. I do not need such a code and only tried helping you...

I am not sure, but I guess OP wants to extract the images on the sheet and create image files to be stored on the PC..... may be he wants to send the file with the images on the sheet to a remote computer (i.e. someone else) and the other user will extract the images on his computer.
So, if this is the case the following code will do the job. Images will be exported as "bmp" files in the folder which houses the excel file itself.
The related sheet name is Sheet1 and below is the image of the sheet what it looks like.

.
Images will be extracted with file names listed in Column B
Following code is prepared and tested on Excel 2010 (64 Bit). Code is placed in a standard code module named Module1
#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" _
            (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hLibModule As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OleCreatePictureIndirectAut Lib "oleAut32.dll" Alias "OleCreatePictureIndirect" _
            (PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, iPic As IPicture) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OleCreatePictureIndirectPro Lib "olepro32.dll" Alias "OleCreatePictureIndirect" _
            (PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, iPic As IPicture) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CopyEnhMetaFile Lib "gdi32" Alias "CopyEnhMetaFileA" _
            (ByVal hemfSrc As LongPtr, ByVal lpszFile As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CopyImage Lib "user32" _
            (ByVal handle As LongPtr, ByVal un1 As Long, ByVal n1 As Long, ByVal n2 As Long, _
            ByVal un2 As Long) As LongPtr
#ElseIf Win32 Then
    Private Declare Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" _
           (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hLibModule As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function OleCreatePictureIndirectAut Lib "oleAut32.dll" Alias "OleCreatePictureIndirect" _
            (PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, iPic As IPicture) As Long
    Private Declare Function OleCreatePictureIndirectPro Lib "olepro32.dll" Alias "OleCreatePictureIndirect" _
            (PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, iPic As IPicture) As Long
    Private Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function CopyEnhMetaFile Lib "gdi32" Alias "CopyEnhMetaFileA" _
            (ByVal hemfSrc As Long, ByVal lpszFile As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function CopyImage Lib "user32" _
            (ByVal handle As Long, ByVal imageType As Long, ByVal NewWidth As Long, ByVal NewHeight As Long, _
            ByVal lFlags As Long) As Long
#End If
'
#If Win64 Then
    Private Type uPicDesc
        Size As Long
        Type As Long
        hPic As LongPtr
        hPal As LongPtr
    End Type
#ElseIf Win32 Then
    Private Type uPicDesc
       Size As Long
       Type As Long
       hPic As Long
       hPal As Long
    End Type
#End If
'
Private Type GUID
   Data1 As Long
   Data2 As Integer
   Data3 As Integer
   Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type
'
Private Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Private Const CF_PALETTE = 9
Private Const CF_ENHMETAFILE = 14
Private Const IMAGE_BITMAP = 0
Private Const LR_COPYRETURNORG = &H4
Private Const PICTYPE_BITMAP = 1
Private Const PICTYPE_ENHMETAFILE = 4
'
Sub ExtractImages()
    Dim NoB As Integer, i As Integer, fileName As String
    
    NoB = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To NoB
        fileName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Text
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
        Call GetPicture(fileName)
    Next
End Sub
'
Sub GetPicture(fileName As String)
    Dim hWndClipboard As Long, lPicType As Long
    Dim uPicinfo As uPicDesc, iPic As IPicture
    Dim IID_IDispatch As GUID
    
    #If Win64 Then
        Dim hPtr As LongPtr, hCopy As LongPtr, hPal As LongPtr, hLib As LongPtr, RetVal As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim hPtr As Long, hCopy As Long, hPal As Long, hLib As Long, RetVal As Long
    #End If
    
    On Error GoTo errHandler:
    
    If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_BITMAP) <> 0 Then
        lPicType = CF_BITMAP
    ElseIf IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_ENHMETAFILE) <> 0 Then
        lPicType = CF_ENHMETAFILE
    End If
    
    hWndClipboard = OpenClipboard(0&)
    
    If hWndClipboard > 0 Then
        hPtr = GetClipboardData(lPicType)
        
        If lPicType = CF_BITMAP Then
            hCopy = CopyImage(hPtr, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_COPYRETURNORG)
        Else
            hCopy = CopyEnhMetaFile(hPtr, vbNullString)
        End If
        
        CloseClipboard
        
        If hPtr = 0 Then Exit Sub
        
        With IID_IDispatch
            .Data1 = &H20400
            .Data2 = 0
            .Data3 = 0
            .Data4(0) = &HC0
            .Data4(1) = 0
            .Data4(2) = 0
            .Data4(3) = 0
            .Data4(4) = 0
            .Data4(5) = 0
            .Data4(6) = 0
            .Data4(7) = &H46
        End With
        
        With uPicinfo
            .Size = Len(uPicinfo)
            .Type = IIf(lPicType = CF_BITMAP, PICTYPE_BITMAP, PICTYPE_ENHMETAFILE)
            .hPic = hCopy
            .hPal = 0
        End With
        
        hLib = LoadLibrary("oleAut32.dll")
        
        If hLib <> 0 Then
            RetVal = OleCreatePictureIndirectAut(uPicinfo, IID_IDispatch, True, iPic)
        Else
            RetVal = OleCreatePictureIndirectPro(uPicinfo, IID_IDispatch, True, iPic)
        End If
        
        FreeLibrary hLib
        
        If RetVal <> 0 Then Exit Sub
        SavePicture iPic, ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & fileName & ".bmp"
    Else
        MsgBox "Cannot copy the picture"
        Exit Sub
    End If
errHandler:
    CloseClipboard
    If Err.Number <> &H0 Then MsgBox getStatus(Err.Number)
End Sub
'
Private Function getStatus(lngErrNum As Long) As String
    Const error_ABORT  As Long = &H80004004
    Const error_ACCESSDENIED  As Long = &H80070005
    Const error_FAIL  As Long = &H80004005
    Const error_HANDLE  As Long = &H80070006
    Const error_INVALIDARG  As Long = &H80070057
    Const error_NOINTERFACE  As Long = &H80004002
    Const error_NOTIMPL  As Long = &H80004001
    Const error_OUTOFMEMORY  As Long = &H8007000E
    Const error_POINTER  As Long = &H80004003
    Const error_UNEXPECTED  As Long = &H8000FFFF
    Const status_OK  As Long = &H0

    Select Case lngErrNum
        Case error_ABORT
            getStatus = "Aborted"
        Case error_ACCESSDENIED
            getStatus = "Access Denied"
        Case error_FAIL
            getStatus = "General Failure"
        Case error_HANDLE
            getStatus = "Bad/Missing Handle"
        Case error_INVALIDARG
            getStatus = "Invalid Argument"
        Case error_NOINTERFACE
            getStatus = "No Interface"
        Case error_NOTIMPL
            getStatus = "Not Implemented"
        Case error_OUTOFMEMORY
            getStatus = "Out of Memory"
        Case error_POINTER
            getStatus = "Invalid Pointer"
        Case error_UNEXPECTED
            getStatus = "Unknown Error"
        Case status_OK
            getStatus = "Success!"
        Case Else
            getStatus = "Error No: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                        "Description: " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                        "Source: " & Err.Source
    End Select
End Function


So, this method copies the image to clipboard and paste into a new file. This approach is what we currently use, but we encountered an issue with pdf files. While it is possible to add an image from a pdf file, it only adds the first page. So, I thought if it would be possible to access the original file in the shape object and read the data from there.
We cannot trust that the original file is still present on the user's computer, or that it is still in the same directory.

You were talking about image files and now pdf files. Are you embedding the PDF files as objects into the sheet and now, trying to extract to user's PC ? Your original question and comment do not match, you are not clear.

Sorry, writing a question is hard. I use Shapes.AddPicture for image and pdf files, then later, use copy paste method to writhe the image back to a temporary file so that I can send it to our API, and it works as long as the pdf has only one page. But if pdf has multiple pages, only first one is sent to the API.

For a PDF file, you need to embed the file as an object. This can be done by VBA and then  it can be extracted again as a PDF file by VBA.

Thanks for the suggestion. object looks promising.
